# What visa do I need for a layover in Kuwait?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, layovers, kuwait

I live in Germany and will be flying from Frankfurt (Germany) to Ahmedabad (India). I will have a layover of 23 hours in Kuwait as I am flying with Kuwait Airways.

I have an Indian passport and would like to use this opportunity to explore the city.

1. Can I get a transit visa at the airport (and can I exit the airport with a transit visa)?
2. How much does it cost for Indian passport holders?
3. As I have a 23-hour layover, would the airline provide me with a free hotel stay?
4. If either free hotel or transit visa are not possible, can I use one of the waiting areas or lounges to sleep for the night (i.e. stay at the airport for 23 hours)?

Comment: Please split this into separate questions: one about the transit visa, one about the free hotel and one about the lounges. Thank you.